# Can I use a single dimmer switch to control multiple lights?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I want to setup a parallel circuit for 10 light fixtures.... Can I use 1 dimmer switch to control all 10 light fixtures all at the same time?  Is this possible to make?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you asking about how to wire the circuit, or about whether one dimmer can control ten fixtures?

Comment: hi thanks for responding, im actually planning to make a d.i.y vanity mirror for my wife as a gift for her birthday..... any suggestions on how to properly wire the 10 bulbs and add a control to intensity of the light all at the same time?

Comment: That is a great idea. You can certainly control the 10 lamps of a vanity mirror with a dimmer. I expect you will find that you want bulbs of no more than 25W each. This is a total load of 250W. Dimmers are commonly available in 150W, 300W, 600W and 1000W. So you won't even have to shop for anything special.

Comment: You have to choose the bulb type first, then purchase the proper dimmer for that type. By bulb type I mean incandescent, CFL, or LED.

Comment: Understood, thank you so much I hope I can do this correctly.... Ive been watching some vids on how to wire those receptacles properly... cross fingers... Have a great weekend ahead

Comment: You do wire all the lamps in parallel.

Comment: Gerard, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site operates.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

A given switch has a specified limit on the total power it can control. Add up the total wattage of all the bulbs and if this is less than the limit for that dimmer, then it should work. Note that for LEDs you use the actual wattage not the equivalent wattage for an incandescent which gives the same illuminance (lumens).

Also the dimmer switch must be one which is designed to control LEDs. A dimmer switch from decades ago probably won't work. For years I used a 30 year old programmable dimmer which was approved for incandescent bulbs to control an LED by using one incandescent and one LED in the two bulb fixture.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the response, very informative.... im actually planning to make a d.i.y vanity mirror for my wife as a gift for her birthday..... any suggestions on how to properly wire the 10 bulbs and add a control to intensity of the light all at the same time?

Comment: Will you tie into an existing circuit or will you be putting in an entirely new circuit back to the panel with a new circuit breaker? If the former, what is the size of the breaker: 15 A or 20 A?

Comment: Will you be making a multi-bulb light fixture that you will plug into a receptacle or will this be "hard wired" into house wiring? Will this be used in the bathroom or in another room away from a lavatory and in a dry environment?

Comment: Hi, i apologize im a noob when it comes to electrical.  I was planning to wire the receptacles together and plug it directly to an outlet.  Is it ok to set it up that way? or do i need to check first if the circuit breaker can accommodate the possible additional load? and also this will be placed inside the bedroom.

Comment: Yes, it is OK to set it up this way. LEDs are so efficient that you can reasonably expect that the circuit would support the additional load. The best way to proceed is to buy a good quality pre-wired  string of LEDs with an inline switch and plug and fit this around a mirror that you construct. You will have to search around to find this. But if you can't find want you want, you could also buy sockets for screw base LED bulbs or other types of sockets and wire them yourself. To test the circuit, plug a lamp into it or some other device and see if the circuit works.

Comment: I did something like this years back using inexpensive fixtures that I made some nice oak framework to hide the cheap metal fixtures, I purchases a very nice beveled glass mirror for the middle and my wife loved it, she could adjust for day light or evening light level to put makeup on (I could not tell the difference) but it made her very happy. Note if plugging it in you might want to consider LED lamps or low wattage incandescent. My opinion on cfl and dimmers is not the best because of failures.

Comment: Why do you assume that the project involves LED lights?  There's nothing in the question indicating that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that LED’s output power is not what draws from the outlet. A typical 60W draws between 4.5W to 9.5W depends on mfg. So if you have 10 lights of 60W each that draws 6.7W each that is  6.7x10 = 67W total. On a 150W dimmer you’ll be only using 44% of it full potential which is perfect.
When using a dimmer don’t exceed 80% of it power potential as a safety precaution and also keeping on account other devices plugged into the same circuit.

Omhs Law Formula: (W=E x I)
W=Power
E=Voltage
I=Current